# Problema con BufferStrategy y JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer un programa en el que pueda utilizar Graphics con BufferStrategy, para poder dibujar por ejemplo un circulo encima de otro y que respete el orden sin que oscilen. Y ademas poder utilizar los componentes de tipo Jpanel en el que pueda ir metiendo botones y alternar entre paneles.
El problema que tengo ahora es que no consigo hacer que el panel deje de parpadear.

Aquí esta el código:

```
public class Partida implements Runnable{

    private JFrame fondo;
    private JPanel panelAbajo;

    public final static int WIDTH = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    public final static int HEIGHT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    private Thread game;
    private boolean running;

    private Principal principal;

    private Jugador rojo;
    private Jugador azul;

    public Partida(Principal principal, Jugador rojo, Jugador azul) {
        this.rojo = rojo;
        this.azul = azul;
        this.fondo = new JFrame();
        this.panelAbajo = new JPanel();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        fondo.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        fondo.setResizable(false);
        fondo.setUndecorated(true);
        fondo.setVisible(true);
        fondo.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        fondo.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0));

        panelAbajo.setSize(1000, HEIGHT-600);
        panelAbajo.setVisible(true);
        panelAbajo.setLocation(50, 600);
        panelAbajo.setBackground(new Color(255));
        panelAbajo.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        fondo.add(panelAbajo);
        start();
    }

    public void tick() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = fondo.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            fondo.createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 1000, 550);
        panelAbajo.repaint();


        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            render();
        }
        stop();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        game = new Thread(this, "game");
        game.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = false;
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

En caso de que no se pueda hacer así, ¿para hacer algo de esto como tendría que enfocarlo?

Comment: hola, lo primero gracias por contestar. He revisado lo que me has dicho, y efectivamente para los render no he puesto control ninguno. Hace todos los que puede. Y ticks si he puesto control, pero no es cada 60 nanosegundos. Es 60 por segundo. Para confirmalos he puesto unos contadores en el código y efectivamente cada segundo cuenta 60 tick y 300 render. Pero la cuestión era que como podría conseguir que el panel dejara de parpadear o como enfocar el programa para conseguir lo que quiero.

Comment: Oops... fallo mío. Te habría respondido al problema de base, pero por lo poco que sé sobre Swing no veo nada que parezca estar mal.

Answer (score 1):

Elimina la línea

```
panelAbajo.repaint()
```

y utiliza un `javax.swing.Timer` para llamar al repaint en forma periódica.

---

Al llamar al repaint dentro de un ciclo con un delay tan pequeño, hace que haga trabajar muy pesado al `RepaintManager`.

De hecho si se mueve el mouse rápido sobre la pantalla, se notará que el panel se dejará de repintar por un pequeño lapso, ya que está tan ocupado repintando que el simple procesamiento del movimiento del mouse termina de sobrecargar de trabajo al procesador.

Al usar el Timer, se desliga el repintado del hilo principal, y con esto se puede configurar el Timer de repintado con un delay superior y no recargar tanto al procesador, cumpliendo la misma función.

Comment: Al llamar al repaint dentro de un ciclo con un delay tan pequeño hace que el RepaintManager tenga mucho trabajo y todo se vuelva muy pesado. De hecho si se mueve el mouse rápido sobre la pantalla se notará que el panel se dejará de repintar por un pequeño lapso, ya que esta tan ocupado repintando que el simple procesamiento del movimiento del mouse termina de sobrecargar de trabajo al procesador. Al usar el Timer se desliga, el repintado del hilo principal y con esto se puede setear el Timer de repintado con un delay superior y no recargar tanto al procesador, cumpliendo la misma función.

Comment: De todas maneras no me queda claro lo que estas buscando @David ya que haces repaint() de un panel sin haber cambiado nada antes en el. Si podes agrega mas info y codigo a tu pregunta asi podemos ayudarte.